# django: how to pass css to form.as_ul

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

my form is

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    ability = forms.ChoiceField(widget= forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices = SKILLS, required=False)
```

i am displaying it as `{{ Form.as_ul }}`

how do i pass a css ul class to this? Can i do it somewhere in the template? not sure how this works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to create a new widget, but you can use the `__init__` and `render` functions of the existing `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget.

Add a new `ul_attrs` parameter to the contructor.

```
from django import forms    
from django.forms.util import flatatt
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MyCheckboxSelectMultiple(forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
def __init__(self, attrs=None, ul_attrs=None):
    self.ul_attrs = ul_attrs
    super(MyCheckboxSelectMultiple, self).__init__(attrs)

def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
    html = super(MyCheckboxSelectMultiple, self).render(name, value, attrs, choices)
    final_attrs = self.build_attrs(self.ul_attrs)
    return mark_safe(html.replace('<ul>','<ul%s>' % flatatt(final_attrs)))
```

In your form simply use this custom widget:

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    ability = forms.ChoiceField(widget= MyCheckboxSelectMultiple(ul_attrs={"class":"fancybox"}), choices = SKILLS,    required=False)
    #
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass HTML attributes to the widget via the `attrs` parameter. Also, take a look at [chapter 7](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/) of the [Django book](http://djangobook.com), especially the section *Customizing Form Design*.

Section teaser:

> While it’s convenient to have our form’s HTML generated for us, in many cases you’ll want to override the default rendering. `{{ form.as_table }}` and friends are useful shortcuts while you develop your application, but everything about the way a form is displayed can be overridden, mostly within the template itself, and you’ll probably find yourself doing this.

Answer (score 0):

since Django 1.11, you can [Overriding built-in widget templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/#overriding-built-in-widget-templates)：

```
class MyCheckboxSelectMultiple(forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    template_name = 'widgets/multiple_input.html'
```

and copy

`django/forms/widgets/multiple_input.html`, which included by `django/forms/widgets/checkbox_select.html`

to

`your_app/templates/widgets` directory.

---

Now, customize  class or style in `your_app/templates/widgets/multiple_input.html` file.