# django - how to arrange form select into multiple column

Tags: django, templates

Below is

forms.py:

```
GRADE_CHOICE=(
               ('1','Grade 1'),
               ('2','Grade 2'),
               ('3','Grade 3'),
               ('4','Grade 4'),
               ('5','Grade 5'),
               ('6','Grade 6') )

grades=forms.MultipleChoiceField(
               choices=GRADE_CHOICE,
               required=True, 
               widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Template.html:

```
< divclass="controls">
{{ form.grades }}
< /div>
```

Above code works fine and templates show correct data. However, it show data in only one column or line by line.

```
<ul>
    <li><label for="id_grades_0"><input type="checkbox" name="grades" value="1" id="id_grades_0" /> Grade 1</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_grades_1"><input type="checkbox" name="grades" value="2" id="id_grades_1" /> Grade 2</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_grades_2"><input type="checkbox" name="grades" value="3" id="id_grades_2" /> Grade 3</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_grades_3"><input type="checkbox" name="grades" value="4" id="id_grades_3" /> Grade 4</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_grades_4"><input type="checkbox" name="grades" value="5" id="id_grades_4" /> Grade 5</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_grades_5"><input type="checkbox" name="grades" value="6" id="id_grades_5" /> Grade 6</label></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to change it so it will display 3 records in one line?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with style, this is a simple example and it can be accomplished in many ways.

Style:

```
li.three  { width:33.333%;float:left;display:inline }
```

Markup:

```
<ul>
     <li class='three'>A</li>
     <li class='three'>B</li>
     <li class='three'>C</li>
     <li class='three'>D</li>
     <li class='three'>E</li>
     <li class='three'>F</li>
     <li class='three'>G</li>
     <li class='three'>H</li>
</ul>

#to add the style use the "attrs" kwarg.
grades=forms.MultipleChoiceField(
           choices=GRADE_CHOICE,
           required=True, 
           widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'three'}))
```

Alternatively, you could customize the `render` function, but style is simpler and will get the job done.

I can't stand the markup having the class on every li versus on the ul.  [You can also customize the render function to allow the style to be put on the ul vs li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448102/django-how-to-pass-css-to-form-as-ul).